# Trying to put up a one liner in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
C       t   s   u   v
0.0001  1   2   3   4
0.0002  5   6   7   8
0.0003  9   0   1   2
...
37 in total
```

K = SUM [C * a1^t * a2^s * a3^u * a4^v]

*Although not precisely correct, I gather most of you will figure out how the above looks like.*

a's are known.

***Is it possible to do this as a one liner in Excel, instead of making another column for the product, then summing them up down below?***

Comment: where are the As stored?

Comment: @nutsch - Anywhere within that sheet. They're constant so ... $N$34 is a1, and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this formula, entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter as an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A34*$N$34^B2:B34*$N$35^C2:C34*$N$36^D2:D34*$N$37^E2:E34)
```